# Adjust vertical spacing in mobile menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with two views.  One is regular pc view the other is a media query view for smaller devices.  When the menu on mobile devices is used the vertical spacing of each of the menu titles is too far apart, so the FAQ is not clearly visible and ABOUT is the very top of the menu.  It looks fine on PC and laptop.

```css
body.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: rgba(67, 67, 68, 0.867);
  backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
  /*  blur amount */
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(9px);
  /* Safari */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  color: rgba(198, 198, 198, 0.945);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}


/*main body*/

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: none;
  width: 40%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-links a {
  display: block;
  text-transform: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: Roboto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: -20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /*border-bottom:-1px solid transparent;*/
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  margin-bottom: 23px;
  /* add margin to increase spacing */
}

.menu {
  line-height: 3vh;
}

.nav-links a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
}

.burger div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 6px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5vw;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0vh;
    min-height: 100vh;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 100vh;
    /*screen cover on expand*/
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: rgb(22, 22, 23);
    /*transparent menu*/
    width: auto;
    max-width: none;
    height: 2px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    white-space: normal;
    transform: translateX(100vh);
    transition: All 0.2s ease-in;
    z-index: 9999;
    /* added z-index to ensure the menu is on top */
  }
  /* increase font size on mobile devices only */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links a {
      font-size: 25px;
      /* adjust font size for mobile devices */
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      padding: 3px 0;
    }
  }
  .nav-links a {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
    /*position:fixed; /* added by me */
    z-index: 99999;
    /* added z-index to ensure the burger icon is on top */
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  nav {
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 5vw;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 100%;
    transition: All 0.2s ease;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
}


/* bump PC screen text down */

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav-links {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-2px, 2px);
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-3px, -3px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">SEE MORE</a>
    <a href="#">MAP</a>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a>

  </ul>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've adjusted some of padding and margin bottom properties but not of it seems to have any effect.  I've experimented with some of the media query properties but none of it has changed anything.